# Follow the keyboard selection in Ubuntu preferably by Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, keyboard, automation, mouse

I am doing automation of my application. To do this at one point I need to move my mouse to selected item. I shall select the item with my keyboard and mouse will move accordingly to that point. Is there any code for doing this in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10. I am using Python for automation.

Comment: Can you get the coordinates of the item selected?

Comment: @sequenceGeek No I cannot. It would make my work a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you:

- Know the coordinates of the "item" you've selected in your application
- Are using Ubuntu

You can do this inside your python script:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["xdotool", "mousemove", "300", "500"])
```

You might have to install xdotool if you don't have it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

You may want to `man xdotool` to get more information on it - it's pretty awesome for automating keyboard/mouse events!

Comment: Co-ordinates may change with the window position. Your solution is good but not optimized. Then I need to get the co ordinate of the selected item.

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure if you're running a desktop/web/etc app?  It should be able to get the Window position of the application

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use xdotool click --delay 1 1 command in python

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure what the "1 1" is but you should be able to use the same code snippet but replace mousemove with click:  `call(["xdotool", "click", "--delay", "1"]`

Comment: First 1 was for delay and 2nd 1 was for left mouse click, but thanks anyway, I think I can work this out.